# How to handle permissions of role in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

What is the best practice of creating a client role and assigning permissions to it? Should I use `Groups` as role and `Roles` as permissions, or make use of `composite roles`?

Comment: I believe both approaches have their respective advantages, and usually, choosing any depends on factors such as the complexity/scale of your application, the flexibility required in managing roles and permissions, and other preferences.  without the business requirement, it isn't easy to evaluate your specific use case or advise on an approach that best meets your requirements.
can you provide more for the expected requirement?